# shared_ptr with custom deleter and allocator

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm writing in c++ but I have some problem with the RAII.

I'd like to build a custom class using a pointer to a struct as a private member.

```
struct mystruct;
typedef struct mystruct mystruct_t;

class container
{
public:
  container();
private:
  shared_ptr<mystruct_t> data;
  mystruct* init();
  void destroy(mystruct*);
};
```

in the constructor of the class i'd like to construct the smart pointer passing it allocator and destructor methods. Theese two methods comes from a library(they prepare the structure, after they allocate memory) and I can't modify them. So I thought to wrap them inside two class methods(I called them init and destroy).

I thought the delegate constructor of the shared_ptr was something like this

```
container()
: data(nullptr, std::bind(&container::destroy), std::bind(&container::init) )
{}
```

but it does not work.
Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: You don't need `typedef struct`s in C++'

Comment: Euhm, in fact the struct comes from a c library that I have to wrap. I tried to summarize all the involved code to be clearer.
I already know this but thanks however! :)

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your `destroy()` and `init()` methods are non-`static` members, they first of all need an object to work on and second they probably need to take some arguments. That is, I would expect the `bind()` expression to look more like

```
data(nullptr,
     std::bind(&container::destroy, some_container, _1),
     std::bind(&container::init, some_container))
```

That said, I doubt that you will have much fun with the allocator: You'd probably be best off to set the `std::shared_ptr<mystruct>` initially to be default constructed and assign the constructed resource once you got hold of it:

```
this->data = std::shared_ptr<mystruct>(container->init(),
                                       std::bind(&container::destroy, container, _1));
```

The third argument to a `std::shared_ptr<T>`'s constructor is an allocator and they are more complicated beasts than just something dealing with construction of an object.

Comment: I thought to pass instead of a nullptr the result of the init() method and then just the deleter functional. But I like the elegant things and I'd like to deal with the allocators :)
Some link to pass me? It's three hours I look for something all over the net.

Comment: @user2714602: allocators do many things and the interface you got to create your object doesn't fit that! Although I can imagine that you can make an allocator do the Right Thing (in which case it would also take care of deallocation, BTW) I wouldn't go down that route for something which creates ready made objects.